# OSX bash "sleep"

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to suspend or "sleep" a specific line in a bash script running in OSX.  The script runs at startup before login.  I'm not seeing the results I'm expecting.  In other words no matter what time I specify after "sleep" the script still moves right along with no delay what so ever.  However when I run the script after login, the "sleep" command seems to work just fine.

Is it possible that the command file "sleep" isn't in the path before login or before my script runs?  Would it help if I placed the path to sleep before the command?  If so where does "sleep" live?

Is there another approach or alternative command I could try?

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create the bin directory
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin

sleep 10

#Copy the files to the Hard Drive
sudo cp /Volumes/NO\ NAME/adbind.bash /usr/local/bin/adbind.bash
sudo cp /Volumes/NO\ NAME/com.sjusd.adbind.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sjusd.adbind.plist

#Fix permissions
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sjusd.adbind.plist
sudo chmod 755 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sjusd.adbind.plist

exit 0
```

Dang tough crowd I got a minus 1 LOL

Comment: What results are you expecting? Could you show the script? Any output? `sleep` is btw. usually located in `/bin/sleep`.

Comment: `echo $(which sleep)` at start of your script, for test your question.

Comment: Zulu that did verify that it's in the /bin directory. Thank you.  It's just not working before the login.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you *know* that it isn't sleeping? Are you sure that you know when the script launches, and have you measured the execution time?

Comment: There's actually a different script involved, the above script was a test I can basically count it when run manually in terminal after login that this one is working.  The other script, I've bumped the sleep up to "sleep 5m" and because the login window appears way before then tells me it's not working.

Answer (score 38):

This might be a little late, but it seems that sleep on OS X doesn't work with quantifiers (m,h, ...). [Official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sleep.3.html)

So "sleep 5m" is the same as "sleep 5". If you want 5 minutes, you have to use "sleep 300"

Comment: "A little late" is a slight understatement. But it is probably the correct answer, so have an upvote.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @rici "slight understatement" is quite an understatement.

Answer (score 5):

If you run `which sleep`, you can get the path to 'sleep' on your system. I get `/bin/sleep`.

At this point, you have a couple of options:

you can specify the path to `sleep` when you call it

```
#!/bin/bash
# script before sleep ...
/bin/sleep
# ... after sleep
```

or you can add the path to your `$PATH` variable within your script before you call it.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/bin"
# script before sleep ...
sleep
# ... after sleep
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help.  When I look in /bin I don't see sleep.  But it must be somewhere if it works when I'm logged in.  OSX version is 10.8.2

Comment: I added the echo $(which sleep) and it does show it's in the /bin directory. I added the PATH and I added /bin/sleep before the command.  I just don't get it.  UGH

Comment: What happens when you run `which sleep` from the command line? It's possible (however unlikely) that `/bin/sleep` is broken, but that there's a working `sleep` earlier in your `$PATH` when launched interactively.